# C# lambda-> All rows Select Add Row_Number

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have a table:

```
DataTable store_temp = new DataTable(); 
store_temp.Columns.Add("patn");
store_temp.Columns.Add("rf");
store_temp.Columns.Add("name");
store_temp.Columns.Add("conv");
store_temp.Columns.Add("conv_type");
store_temp.Columns.Add("recorddate");
store_temp.Columns.Add("executiondate");
```

My C# code :

```
int i = 0;
var rowsgroups = (from row in store_temp.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row =>
row.Field<string>("patn"))
.OrderBy((g => g.OrderByDescending(y => y.Field<string("executiondate")).ThenByDescending(y =>
y.Field<string>("rf"))))
select new
{
    patn = row.ElementAt(i),
    rf_num = ++i,
}).ToArray();
```

I want the lambda experession, which is equivalent to:

> > ```
> > select patn, rf,
> > ```
> >
> > **>     row_number() over( partition by  patn order by  executiondate,rf ) 
> >     as rf_num,**
>
> ```
>      name, conv,conv_type, recorddate, executiondate 
>       from store_temp2
> ```

**But, lambda syntax  ... var rowsgroups has just a one row..
I want to show  all rows in store_temp.
What should I do to fix the query?**

Comment: I want just a add  column row_number  .. and change the sql to lambda experession..

Comment: Your required `lamba .. sql` does not' contain any group by .. it only required order-by for row_number.. did you miss there any thing??

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827370/how-to-get-row-number-via-linq-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> row_number() over(partition by patn order by executiondate, rf)

means in LINQ you need to group by `patn`, then order **each group** by `executiondate, rf`, then use the indexed `Select` overload to get row numbering inside the group, and finally flatten the result with `SelectMany`.

With that being said, the equivalent LINQ query could be something like this:

```
var result = store_temp.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(e => e.Field<string>("patn"), (key, elements) => elements
        .OrderBy(e => e.Field<string>("executiondate"))
        .ThenBy(e => e.Field<string>("rf"))
        .Select((e, i) => new
        {
            patn = key,
            rf = e.Field<string>("rf"),
            rf_num = i + 1,
            name = e.Field<string>("name"),
            conv = e.Field<string>("conv"),
            conv_type = e.Field<string>("conv_type"),
            recorddate = e.Field<string>("recorddate"),
            executiondate = e.Field<string>("executiondate")
        }))
    .SelectMany(elements => elements)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select new
{
    rowNum = store_temp.Rows.IndexOf(row),
    patn = row.ElementAt(i),
    rf_num = ++i,
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: that is a error .. store_temp.Rows.IndexOf(row)
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataRowCollection.IndexOf(System.Data.DataRow)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Does your code give an error?  The variable row should be a DataRow, not sure why you not are getting an error without my change.  Code should work if current code is working.

Comment: Error2 .. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Data.DataRow'..  :'( .....

Comment: You can't cast a List<> object to a singular.  So you need to add to code FirstOrDefault() method to Linq.  The real problem is the Group is a List<DataRow>.  So you need two nested 'select' methods.  First to enumerate through the groups (List<DataRow>).  The 2nd to enumerate through the rows in the groups.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you required any `groupby` as per your `required sql`

```
        var i=0;
        var rowsgroups = (from row in store_temp.AsEnumerable()
                          orderby row.Field<string>("executiondate") descending,
                          row.Field<string>("rf") descending
                          select new
                            {
                                patn = row.Field<string>("patn"),
                                rf_num = ++i,
                                name = row.Field<string>("name"),
                                conv = row.Field<string>("conv"),
                                conv_type = row.Field<string>("conv_type"),
                                recorddate = row.Field<string>("recorddate"),
                                executiondate = row.Field<string>("executiondate") 
                            }).ToArray();
```

Comment: no,..nono i want .. partition by patn column.. .. how can is use the partition by in lambda expression???