# Get row_number of a single record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table with many records,

This table contains a chart,
I would like to get the position of a single user:

Here is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
var res = _context.Chart
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.Score)
             .SkipWhile(x => x.Username != username)
             .Select((t, i) => new { idx = i })
```

This gives an error, I tried many combination but I can't get it to work.

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet .OrderByDescending(r => r.Score) .SkipWhile(x => x.Username != __username_0)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Any idea of how I should do it?
Thanks!

Update:
The following code works!

```
_context.Chart
                .AsEnumerable()
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Score)
                .Select((t, i) => new { Index = i, t.Score, t.Username })
                .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Username == username);
```

But I am worried about performance, do you think it can cause problems? thanks

Comment: What error? Your code seems to be the same as the proposed solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4827558/3181933).

Comment: Yes it is.. here is the error:
Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Chart>
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Score)
    .SkipWhile(x => x.Username != __username_0)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Comment: I wonder if it's struggling to convert the `.SkipWhile` part?

Comment: does it help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59282608/6527049

Comment: @Llama I tried without the skipWhile, it gives the same error:

await _context.Chart
                .Select((t, i) => new { Index = i, Score = t.Score, Username = t.Username })
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Score)
                .Where(x => x.Username == username)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: @viveknuna I also tried to change the settings like the question that you linked, it didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you want scores lower then some users try filtering by score which is lower then max score for that user name:

```cs
var res = _context.Chart
    .Where(r => r.Score <= _context.Chart.Where(x => x.Username != username).Max(x => x.Score))
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Score)
    .Select((t, i) => new { idx = i })
```

If you want row number of concrete user then you will need to have the select before the filtering. Try something like this:

```
var res = _context.Chart
    .Select((t, i) => new { rownum = i, t.Score, t.Username })
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Score)
    .Where(x => x.Username == username)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: As per his question I think `Max(x => x.Score)` is not requred

Comment: Just tried.. I get the same error:
Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Chart>
    .Select((t, i) => new { 
        Index = i, 
        Score = t.Score, 
        Username = t.Username
     })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Comment: @gabrigabra what database are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron SQL server